# When I run this script in PowerShell, it returns "the global name `print_twice` is not defined"

Tags: python, powershell

This is `para.py`:

```
def print_twice(param):
    print param,param
def cat_twice(part1,part2):
    cat=part1 + part2
    print_twice(cat)
```

When I run `para.py` on PowerShell like this:

```
from para import *
chant1='as'
chant2='da'
cat_twice(chant1,chant2)
```

it returns:

> blabla...
>   the global name 'print_twice' is not defined

Comment: Is the second part another script that you're running like "python script.py", or are you using the interactive Python shell (i.e. the REPL)?

Comment: What do you mean "run `para.py` on PowerShell like this"? The second code snippet is also Python, not PowerShell. How *exactly* are you running the code?

Comment: I can run the script on IDLE normally,but when i try to run it on PowerShell like 2,it did not work.

Comment: Now i am sort of understanding this,when i mean i run para.py on powershell,it should be done like this : input "python para.py" on the command line,not like 2 which i mixed with globle para and local para.Is it right?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. If you run `python .\para.py` (`para.py` being the file with your first code snippet) it shouldn't do anything at all, because the file defines 2 functions without ever invoking them. Please update your question with a [mcve] of the code you have, how *exactly* you run it, and the complete error message you're getting.